# Adding SharePoint calculated field - not all list fields are displayed to choose from

Tags: sharepoint

When I try to create a calculated field, Sharepoint does not offer the list columns i want to include in the calculation (they are text fields that I want to concatenate)

Comment: "Multiple Lines of Text" cannot be used in a Calculated Field.

Answer (score 0):

If those are [Today] and [Me] columns, then those cannot be added directly. These columns need to be created first. Later you can delete those columns once your formula works.